# Writing an object array to csv file in java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, filewriter

I am trying to take an initial CSV file, pass it through a class that checks another file if it has an A or a D to then adds or deletes the associative entry to an array object.

### example of pokemon.csv:

```
1, Bulbasaur
2, Ivysaur
3, venasaur
```

### example of changeList.csv:

```
A, Charizard
A, Suirtle
D, 2
```

That being said, I am having a lot of trouble getting the content of my new array to a new CSV file. I have checked to see whether or not my array and class files are working properly. I have been trying and failing to take the final contents of "pokedex1" object array into the new CSV file.

## Main File

```
import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PokedexManager {

public static void  printArray(String[] array) {
    System.out.print("Contents of array: ");

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if(i == array.length - 1) {
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }else {
            System.out.print(array[i] + ",");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //output for pokedex1 using PokemonNoGaps class
        PokemonNoGaps pokedex1 = new PokemonNoGaps();

        //initializes scanner to read from csv file
        String pokedexFilename = "pokedex.csv";
        File pokedexFile = new File(pokedexFilename);
        Scanner pokescanner = new Scanner(pokedexFile);

        //reads csv file, parses it into an array, and then adds         new pokemon objects to Pokemon class
        while(pokescanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String pokeLine = pokescanner.nextLine();
            String[] pokemonStringArray = pokeLine.split(", ");
            int id = Integer.parseInt(pokemonStringArray[0]);
            String name = pokemonStringArray[1];
            Pokemon apokemon = new Pokemon(id, name);
            pokedex1.add(apokemon);
        }

        //opens changeList.csv file to add or delete entries from         Pokemon class
        String changeListfilename = "changeList.csv";
        File changeListFile = new File(changeListfilename);
        Scanner changeScanner = new Scanner(changeListFile);

        //loads text from csv file to be parsed to PokemonNoGaps class
        while(changeScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String changeLine = changeScanner.nextLine();
            String[] changeStringArray = changeLine.split(", ");
            String action = changeStringArray[0];
            String nameOrId = changeStringArray[1];

            //if changList.csv file line has an "A" in the first spot add this entry to somePokemon
            if(action.equals("A")) {
                int newId = pokedex1.getNewId();
                String name = nameOrId;
                Pokemon somePokemon = new Pokemon(newId, name);
                pokedex1.add(somePokemon);
            }
            //if it has a "D" then send it to PokemonNoGaps class to delete the entry from the array
            else { //"D"
                int someId = Integer.parseInt(nameOrId);
                pokedex1.deleteById(someId);
            }
            //tests the action being taken and the update to the array
            //System.out.println(action + "\t" + nameOrId + "\n");
            System.out.println(pokedex1);

            //*(supposedly)* prints the resulting contents of the array to a new csv file
            String[] pokemonList = changeStringArray;
            try {
                String outputFile1 = "pokedex1.csv";
                FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter(outputFile1);
                writer1.write(String.valueOf(pokemonList));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("\nError writing to Pokedex1.csv!");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //tests final contents of array after being passed through PokemonNoGaps class
        //System.out.println(pokedex1);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

## PokemonNoGaps class file:

```
public class PokemonNoGaps implements ChangePokedex {
    private Pokemon[] pokedex = new Pokemon[1];
    private int numElements = 0;
    private static int id = 0;
    // add, delete, search

    @Override
    public void add(Pokemon apokemon) {
        // if you have space
        this.pokedex[this.numElements] = apokemon;
        this.numElements++;
        // if you don't have space
        if(this.numElements == pokedex.length) {
            Pokemon[] newPokedex = new Pokemon[ this.numElements * 2]; // create new array
            for(int i = 0; i < pokedex.length; i++) { // transfer all     elements from array into bigger array
                newPokedex[i] = pokedex[i];
            }
            this.pokedex = newPokedex;
        }
        this.id++;
    }

    public int getNewId() {
        return this.id + 1;
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteById(int id) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numElements; i++) {
            if(pokedex[i].getId() == id) {
                for(int j = i+1; j < pokedex.length; j++) {
                    pokedex[j-1] = pokedex[j];
                }
                numElements--;
                pokedex[numElements] = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public Pokemon getFirstElement() {
        return pokedex[0];
    }
    public int getNumElements() {
        return numElements;
    }
    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < this.numElements; i++) {
            result += this.pokedex[i].toString() + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

### Excpeted output:

```
1, Bulbasaur
3, Venasaur
4, Charizard
5, Squirtle
```

Am i using the wrong file writer? Am I calling the file writer at the wrong time or incorrectly? In other words, I do not know why my output file is empty and not being loaded with the contents of my array. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spotted a few issues whilst running this. As mentioned in previous answer you want to set file append to true in the section of code that writes to the new pokedx1.csv

```
   try {
        String outputFile1 = "pokedex1.csv";
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(prefix+outputFile1, true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        for(String pokemon : pokedex1.toString().split("\n")) {
            System.out.println(pokemon);
            bw.write(pokemon);
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("\nError writing to Pokedex1.csv!");
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

I opted to use buffered reader for the solution. Another issue I found is that your reading pokedex.csv but the file is named pokemon.csv.

```
String pokedexFilename = "pokemon.csv";
```

I made the above change to fix this issue.

On a side note I noticed that you create several scanners to read the two files. With  these types of resources its good practice to call the close method once you have finished using them; as shown below.

```
Scanner pokescanner = new Scanner(pokedexFile);
// Use scanner code here
// Once finished with scanner
pokescanner.close();
```

Comment: I have close the scanners that I was using. I was actually doing this as I saw this answer. I have changed the name of my original file to pokedex.csv, sorry about the confusion there. I made the changes to the scanner as noted above and now I'm finally getting something to write to the file. Good and bad news. First

Comment: Good =  I have the right information being printed to the file. Bad = The output is being repeated 9 times over. It fills up the top row with all the info in a row and then repeats itself through the next 8 rows of the file. (ex: 1    Bulbasaur3    Venasaur5    Charmeleon...[next line]1    Bulbasaur3    Venasaur5    Charmeleon...[7 more times]. It coincides with the number of elements being used in total. Any ideas why that is happening?

Comment: I noticed in your code that you are using System.out.println for debugging. What IDE are you using to develop as many have debug modes that will help you trace through the code as it is running. That or I suggest you try to write some Junit tests to help ensure your code is doing what you expect.

Comment: I think one of the main problems is that you are writing to the csv file inside of your loop. `while (changeScanner.hasNextLine())` I would try to separate each step of the problem into a specified method. First read files, next remove / add items and finally once you know what you want to add / remove write to the file (this should be done once outside of the loop). Also if you move this code to outside of the loop then you may not want to append to file anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Using separate methods sounds easier than what I was trying to do. I am using Eclipse currently. Everything else seems to be working just fine otherwise!

Comment: No worries. See [how to debug in eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php) learning how to use this will help you visualise what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
String outputFile1 = "pokedex1.csv";
FileWriter writer1 = new FileWriter(outputFile1);
```

appears to be within your `while` loop so a new file will be created every time.

Either use the `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)` constructor or create before the loop

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I will keep that in mind when I use writers from now on! So if I put the constructor before the loop it only calls it once?

Comment: Also, a new file is not being created every time. It is instead appending to the same file every single time I run it. How do I get it to rewrite the file or make a new instance of the file every time?